# How to they film walk on glass scenes in movie?

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography

Like below image, walk on glass intro scene of mass hero is very common in Indian film.

[image]

Like this kind of scenes, how to they use cameras?

Comment: Does anyone know how thick the glass would have to be to achieve this?

Comment: It looks even better from the other side. E.g. [The CN Tower Glass Floor - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI0TCo6c2zc&t=2m1s), which is 342m (1,122 ft) above the ground.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever scene like this are needed to shoot, They usually uses a glass panel placed above the camera.

Actor walks on the glass panel. possible it could be a hardened glass. So actor walks on the glass, camera is located at below the glass, Not touching the glass. Then scene can be shot as normal one. No other special effects used.

Comment: I just want to add that the glass panel, and the actor, and probably several feet above the ground. Before this shot, there are usually shots of the actor walking on the ground normally, and after this shot, there are shots of the actor walking on the ground normally. When this "glass panel" shot is put in the middle, the audience may think that the camera is underground. But that is just an editing technique.

Comment: Great addition. thanks. That few seconds of footage made the whole scene little different and mostly viewer's mind is attracted into that particular few seconds, Walking normally is a normal thing, but seeing someone walks on top of your view, it can be magical sometimes :) , I've just concentrated on that scene only